# Non-compact real forms of $\mathfrak {sl}_3(\mathbb C)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking the non-compact real forms $\mathfrak s$ of $\mathfrak {sl}_3(\mathbb C)$ with $\mathfrak {sl}_3(\mathbb C)=\mathfrak s\oplus i\mathfrak s$? What are the corresponding Lie groups of $\mathfrak s$?

Comment: This is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_form_(Lie_theory)), "In the case of the complex special linear group" ...We have the compact form and the split real form.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So is the only non-compact (totally) real form of the group $SL_3(\mathbb C) $ the real group  $SL_3(\mathbb R) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to isomorphism, there are three real forms of $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb C)$:

> $\mathfrak{g}_1 = \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb R) = \lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
>  a & c & e\\
>  f & b & d\\
>  h & g & -a-b
> \end{pmatrix} : a, ..., h \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$;
>
> $\mathfrak{g}_2 = \mathfrak{su}_{1,2} := \lbrace
> \begin{pmatrix}
>  a+bi & c+di & ei\\
>  f+gi & -2bi & -c+di\\
>  hi & -f+gi & -a+bi
> \end{pmatrix} : a, ..., h \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$;
>
> $\mathfrak{g}_3 = \mathfrak{su}_{3} := \lbrace
> \begin{pmatrix}
>  ia & c+di & g+hi\\
>  -c+di & ib & e+fi\\
>  -g+hi & -e+fi & -ai-bi
> \end{pmatrix} : a, ..., h \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$.

The first one is the split real form, the second one is quasi-split but not split, and the third one is the compact form. I am pretty sure "the" corresponding Lie groups of the non-compact forms would be denoted $SL_3(\mathbb R)$ resp. $SU(1,2)$.

For everything you want to know about these forms and their representation theory, look at [this answer (part "A slightly different example")](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258221/96384). For real forms of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ in general, learn to read [this table](https://books.google.de/books?id=l8nJCNiIQAAC&pg=PA229&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @AmratA No, $SU(1,2)$ has no subgroup of codimension 2. This can be checked more or less by hand.

Comment: Thank you very much